# Why is my Searchbar not working if I type too fast?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I linked a video where you can see that my searchbar isn't working if I type too fast. And here is my Code:

```
List{
                        ForEach(copyOfGeraete.filter({item in self.suchBegriffGeraete.isEmpty ? true : item.lowercased().contains(suchBegriffGeraete.lowercased())}), id: \.self){ item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
                                Text(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

You can download the Video of my Screen while my App is running under "https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20210521Mj4UvG0O"

Thanks for your time, It would be great if someone has a idea why its lagging...

Boothosh

Comment: It's more reliable to filter in the model class with Combine (`debounce` and `CombineLatest`) rather than directly in the view. Apart from that `localizedCaseInsensitiveContains` is more efficient than calling `lowercased()` again and again.

Comment: Do the filtering in a class ViewModel. The body shouldn’t do any work. It is probably being affected by the reload/refresh of the struct